# Produce a function that receives the die value and the total number of rolls and prints a single line of the histogram based on the values passed

Tags: python

"You will need to call the function once per possible die value."

I'm a programming noob and have spent about seven hours trying to figure this out.

My code is just a conglomeration of ideas and hopes that I'm headed in the right direction.  I desperately need help and want to understand this stuff.  I've scoured the message boards for my specific issue in vain.  Please assist...

I realize my code is spitting out the result for every possible roll. When I need a program that I.E. when someone chooses to roll 50 times and designates 2 as the die value they desire to single out.  The histogram would display how many times 2 was randomly rolled out of 50 rolls as asterisks on a single line of histogram.

My code thus far:

```
import random


def dice_sum(rolls):
    results = 0
    dice_sum = 0    
    for i in range(0, rolls):
        results = random.randint(1, 6)
        print("Die %d rolled %d." % (i+1, results))
        dice_sum += results
    print("Total of %d dice rolls is: %d" % (rolls, dice_sum))
    return dice_sum

def hist_gram():
    hist_gram='*'
    dievalue= int(input('Which specific value between 1 and 6 are you requesting? [enter a #]'))


# get user input 
rolls = int(input('How many times would you like to roll the 6 sided die? [enter a #]'))
dievalue= int(input('Which specific value between 1 and 6 are you requesting? [enter a #]'))

# pass input values to function and print result
result = dice_sum(rolls=rolls)
print(result)
```

Comment: So what is your question? Is there an error you need help solving, or are you looking for debugging help? You should consider editing your question to format the code and also make it clear what you are after.

Comment: While many of us are happy to help, you should know a couple things about how the site works. Eliminate noise from the post. Get rid of _everything_ but the _specific problem_. Also, format your code by selecting it and hitting CTRL K :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a mountain out of a molehill. **Slow down** and think about the problem. They want you to do an action a bunch of times. Then based on what each result is, do something with that information.

We can use a `for` loop to do the actions many times, as you've used. Then we can check the result using a simple `if` statement. You're trying to do the processing after the fact and it's making your life more difficult than it needs to be.
Our solution becomes very simple:

```
import random
def dice_count(rolls, reqValue):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, rolls):
        if roll_the_dice() == reqValue:
            count = count + 1
            #Every time we encounter the value, we count up by one
    #That's it! return count.
    #Apparently we want a 'single line of a histogram',
    # which is kind of a pointless histogram, don't you think?
    #Turns out you can multiply against strings.
    return count*'*'


def roll_the_dice():
    #Apparently we need to call the function more than once? Confusing instruction.
    return random.randint(1,6)
```

And now for the input:

You can use a `try..catch` block to deal with bad input. If someone inputs something that's not a number, the `int` conversion will create a ValueError. Instead of crashing, we can decide what happens when a ValueError is raised. If an error occurs, just start over - and keep trying until the user gets it right.

```
def main():
    doInput()


def doInput():
    rolls = 0
    side = 0
    #set up the variables, so we can access them outside the try..catch block
    try:
        rolls = int(raw_input("How many times should the die be rolled? "))
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not a valid number. Try again!"
        doInput()
    try:
        side = int(raw_input("Which side?"))
        if side < 1 or side > 6:
            print "That's not a valid side of a die! Try again!"
            do_input()
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not a valid number. Try again!"
        do_input()
    dice_count(rolls, side)
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I am sorry for the excess commentary in initial question.  I tried to run your example in python but immediately got a syntax error on the second line.  Is that a result of copy and pasting the code?  Also, I am confused about how to tell if a formula works if you don't have user input where you can enter in the numbers yourself and test it out?  Don't you always need user input to know if the code works or do you just assume it works if no error messages pop up?

Comment: Ah. Just a typo. No, this works the same way. If you're using IDLE, you can just run it and type dice_count(50, 3) in the console. If not, yes, you'll want to add input, but put that *outside* of the function, so that the function doesn't always ask for input. 
If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: how would I go about adding input questions outside the function that will be the equivalent of typing dice_count(50,3) or whatever number combo that produces the single line of histogram?  I'm able to ask questions but it doesn't produce results or tie into the functions so I will get a histogram like I need it to.

Comment: I've updated the question. You want to try and keep your logic and input separated from each other, like I've done here. That way, if someone else wants to come along and use your code (in the real world, they will), they're not required to use it in a context that uses input.

Comment: why can't I see it asking for input when I run that code?  It just shows the triple carrot python thing and no input asked when I run those two combined pieces of code together.

Comment: also, it's been clarified that the histogram is supposed to supply outcomes for all the rolls.. i.e.
2s: ****

3s: ********

4s: ***

etc.

The instructions were just misleading and I apologize for not understanding them.  Unfortunately, I'm back to square one on figuring this out.

Comment: If those are the terms of the assignment, I would suggest looking at the answer below. It shows you how to make a histogram that shows the frequency of all 6 sides. Not sure about the input, are you using Python 3 or Python 2?

Comment: 3.5.1 is what is says in about python

Comment: Ah. `raw_input` is for Python 2.7. Try  `input.`

Comment: hmm..is the code below written for 2.7 or is it workable with what I have?

Comment: Everything will work but the `raw_input` vs `input` issue.

Comment: any reason why the format below wouldn't work?  I can't seem to get it to run but yet theres no syntax errors or anything so I assume it works..I'm using IDLE.

Comment: never mind I can't seem to format this stuff correctly

Comment: 1) ew formatting in comments is nonexistent 2) did you call histogram(results)?

Comment: basically I combined the code below with the input section of yours minus the sides since it's wanting a histogram for all possible numbers. Of course, I put input instead of raw_input, as well.  I don't know but I sure appreciate your gracious assistance.  Thanks again for all you've done.

Comment: Extended discussion is not meant to go in the comments, but you can always ask another question if you're still confused.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to store the result of each die role somehow, rather than just adding up the sum of your roles. This will also extend your function to be able to look at the results of all 50 results if you want, or just one roll at a time.

There are a few data structures you could use, but I'd recommend a dictionary because it's the most intuitive when dealing with storing values associated with events. For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import random

def dice_sum(rolls):
    results = defaultdict(int)
    for i in xrange(rolls):
        this_roll = random.randint(1,6)
        results[this_roll] += 1
    return results
```

Running `dice_sum(50)`:

```
>>> results = dice_sum(5)
>>> results[1]
11
>>> results[2]
5
>>> results[3]
6
>>> results[4]
13
>>> results[5]
8
>>> results[6]
7
```

Getting a histogram for a single line has been explained, so if you want the whole thing:

```
def histogram(results):
    hist = ""
    for i in xrange(1,7):
        bar = '#' * results[i]
        hist += '{}: {}\n'.format(i,bar)
    return hist
```

Running it:

```
>>> print histogram(results)
1: ###########
2: #####
3: ######
4: #############
5: ########
6: #######
```